# Apache, Redirect is not working for substring

Tags: apache2, 302-redirect

**Issue**

In apache, how can I redirect to homepage in case if you will go to exact string, but everything behind this string should be displayed normally, no redirect.

Example.

```
http://example.com/STRING -> go to homepage
http://example.com/STRING_PAGE -> go to http://example.com/STRING_PAGE
```

**I tried**

```
Redirect 301 /STRING http://example.com/
```

But in this case page is redirected to homepage too, for example in case of `http://example.com/STRING_PAGE`.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Redirect 301 /STRING http://example.com/
> ```

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive is *prefix-matching*, so the above will match requests for both `/STRING` *and* `/STRING_PAGE`.

You need to use `RedirectMatch` (also part of mod_alias) if you want an exact match - this uses regular expressions to match against the requested URL.

For example, to match `/STRING` only then try the following instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/STRING$ http://example.com/
```

(You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.)

However, if you are already using mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`) for other rewrites/redirects then you may need to use mod_rewrite instead in order to avoid conflicts. For example, the equivalent using mod_rewrite would be:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?STRING$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```